# Better way to add configurations files in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application in ruby, that I want to make some configurations. For example, in development, I want that a user can add only 10 photos on an albun for a certain plan.

Something like this:

```
development: 
  number_photos:10
production:
  number_photos:30
```

And want to acess those values on my controllers. For example. On my photos_controller.rb

```
def get_number_photos
     #how can I read the value of the number_photos of the configuration file? 
end
```

What is the better way to do something like this?

Comment: Use dotenv. It is developed to be used in such scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the `.config.yaml` (name is arbitrary) file in `Rails.root` and fill it with your content.

```
development: 
  number_photos: 10
production:
  number_photos: 30
```

In your controller do:

```
yaml_config =
  YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('.config.yaml'))
number_photos = yaml_config[Rails.env]['number_photos']
```

It’ll set the number according to your current environment setting.

Comment: Looks cool. But my variable number_photos its with value: "number_photos:10". 

How can I acess the value "10", not the string "number_photos:10" ?

Comment: Excuse me? What string? `yaml_config[Rails.env]` returns a hash and `yaml_config[Rails.env]['number_photos']` returns a value.

Comment: Look what is returning:

 number_photos = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('.config.yaml'))[Rails.env][number_photos]

 => "number_photos:10"

Comment: On your answer. number_photos returns "number_photos"

Comment: You have an induced error. I have triple-checked my answer. It is correct and works perfectly, returning `10`. Also in what you pasted there are quotes around `'number_photos'` hash key missing.

Comment: The problem was only a space  on the file. Thank you for the answer